# How can I extract the value from ipairs?

Tags: parsing, lua, command

When I write the command the result is below one.

```
No   ID         Sub-Id             Sig    Mode
22   DarrenIm   00:00:00:1a:00     60     13n/d
32   DarrenYou  00:00:00:1b:01     80     13n/d
```

I want to extract the Sig value(and from comparing the sig values, I want to get highest Sig value and want to get ID in same column). I tried it but I have an problem.
Here is my code.

```
f = assert(io.popen("Here is my command"))

local val = {}

for line in f:lines() do
    print(line)
    for v in line:gmatch'[%d]%d' do
            table.insert(val, v)
    end

    for i, v in ipairs(val) do
            m = math.max(i)
            n = m-1
            sig = v
            print(sig)
    end

print(n)

end

f:close()
```

However, when I used sig[n] there is an error, so I can't extract the value.
And from comparing that values, I want to get the highest signal and to get Id in same column.
How can I do for solving this problem?

Comment: A solution would be to parse the input string. For example, take the function from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47655213/print-table-in-lua

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a look at your code. First you get a file handle

```
f = assert(io.popen("Here is my command"))
```

then you create a table

```
local val = {}
```

You read the file line by line, print it

```
for line in f:lines() do
    print(line)
```

You insert every match for `'[%d]%d'` in each line into your table `val`

```
    for v in line:gmatch'[%d]%d' do
            table.insert(val, v)
    end
```

Now you do something that would only make sense after having parsed all lines of your file into val. But this is done for each line as you are still inside the line-loop.

```
    for i, v in ipairs(val) do
```

i is a number, what is the maximum of a single number? so this line is nonsense.

```
            m = math.max(i)
            n = m-1
```

sig is a global variable. in your case it's a string. so sig[n] will of course give you an error because you can only index table values.

```
            sig = v
            print(sig)
    end

print(n)

end

f:close()
```

The string pattern '[%d]' doesn't make too much sense. [] creates a class of characters. And %d stands for any number. Putting that into a class alone makes no difference to just using %d.

Your code shows that you lack very basic knowledge in Lua. Please do some beginners tutorial befor attempting to parse files.

The structure of your code indicates that you did not really think about the order of operations. Get pen and paper and think befor you start programming.

Comment: I think so too. I'll think more about my problem and also study too. Thanks your comment.